# How do I implement this UML line with package indentifier (~) into usable code?

Tags: java, package, uml

Trying to convert a line from a UML asking for that uses a package identifier into code that I can use.

I've tried looking for package methods but haven't found anything, I'm assuming I'm looking at this the wrong way.

The line in the UML (Visual Paradigm) is as follows:

```
~ addSuggestion(suggestion: BookingSuggestion): void
```

My attempt of converting it to Java was:

```
package void addSuggestion(BookingSuggestion suggestion) {}
```

but that creates a "Syntax error on token "package", delete this token" message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~` indicates that the method should have `package` visibility. That visibility is not an explicit modifier, but instead the *absence* of any modifiers ([details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)):

```
// Public
public void addSuggestion(BookingSuggestion suggestion) {}

// Protected
protected void addSuggestion(BookingSuggestion suggestion) {}

// Package
void addSuggestion(BookingSuggestion suggestion) {}

// Private
private void void addSuggestion(BookingSuggestion suggestion) {}
```

Just remove `package` in your code and you are fine.